# instanciating SolrCrudRepository programmatically, without Spring Boot magic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I have a Spring Boot 2.4 project that is using `spring-boot-starter-data-solr`. Unfortunately, spring-boot-starter-data-solr is not supported anymore (see https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-solr#overview) , so I can't easily upgrade Spring Boot as I usually do for other projects.

However, I thought I would still try to upgrade my project and keep using the latest `spring-boot-starter-data-solr` I could get : maybe it's not supported anymore, but I am not making an extensive use of it, so maybe I can take advantage of latest Spring Boot features for a some more time, before there's really a breaking change and I really can't use `spring-boot-starter-data-solr`

So, I upgraded my project to Spring Boot 2.6.4 letting Spring BOM pull all the latest versions of all dependencies managed. Of course, it failed on spring-boot-starter-data-solr, so I had to declare the version explicitly :

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr:2.4.13'
```

I fixed few other things, and my project compiles. However, at startup (and in some integration tests), I have a problem :

```java
    @Configuration
    public class PersistenceConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public TicketRepository ticketRepository(SolrTicketEntityRepository solrTicketEntityRepository) {
            return new TicketRepositoryImpl(solrTicketEntityRepository);
        }

    ... some other beans..

    }
```

with `SolrTicketEntityRepository` defined like below :

```java
public interface SolrTicketEntityRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<TicketEntity, String> {

  @Query("?0")
  Page<TicketEntity> search(String searchText, Pageable pageable);
```

With Spring Boot 2.6, the SolrTicketEntityRepository doesn't get instanciated anymore, so I have a missing bean at startup. I've tried adding the `@EnableSolrRepositories` on PersistenceConfig, but it doesn't do anything.

is there a way to mimic Spring Boot magic, and trigger programmatically `SolrTicketEntityRepository` / `SolrCrudRepository` instanciation, to be able to start my application ?

or is it way too complicated, and as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427292/3067542) , should I implement the stuff myself with the core Solr libraries without Spring Boot's help (which would be the objective at some point anyway) ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this yet?

Comment: @Euridice01, no I didn't find a solution.. so I am re-implementing it myself for the few methods I was using

Comment: How are you reimplementing it? Did you decide to go with SolrJ or something else? Thanks! Can you share an example of the reimplementation?

Comment: yes, I am going with SolrJ. But I can't share some code as it's not public, sorry